# Horizontal line and repeated header in Pandoc table

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I used Pandoc to convert .md to .docx files and met two troubles:

(1) The header row is repeated through page breaks
(2) Top and bottom horizontal lines are not drawn

How can I solve them?
While I know (1) is the default function added on Pandoc v1.4, I would like to suppress it.

Expected (lines top and bottom of table):
[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ysJV.png)

Indeed (header row is repeated in next page):
[Indeed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vr5H.png)

I used Pandoc via pandoc/ubuntu:2.16.2